# Why my application is showing incompatible on downloading from iTunes on iphone 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Previously , My application was able to download on each device from iTunes. Currently I am working on Xcode 7.2 and have uploaded app to iTunes. Now, it is showing that this app is not compatible to your device when downloading it from iPhone 5. I cannot find the reason for this.

Comment: What OS version is the iPhone?  What did you select as the minimum OS version when building?

Comment: iPhone is using 9.2 OS version and i have selected minimum OS version to 8.0

Comment: @PhillipMills Can you help me? I got stuck in this issue from last 5 days and unable to find the exact issue.

Comment: Sorry, there aren't any clues in what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Log into iTunes connect, select your app and click *Activity*. Under *All Builds*, select the current build available on the App Store and view Device Requirements.

If these are not as expected then you will need to review the preferences you have set in Xcode.

Comment: Yes , I checked it . UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key was missing in my info.plist. I have added it now and now i am able to run it on iPhone 5 . But now when i uploading it to iTunes , its giving me error "The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any iOS device that was supported by previous versions."

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the Deployment Target IOS in your application, to your iPhone5's IOS.

[Deployment Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z597W.png)